# Can an image be redacted, or just text?

Tags: word-usage

Looking at the definition for redact, it sounds as if it specifically applies to text. Can it be used with images and diagrams as well?

Comment: We've got some conflicting answers because there are two pretty different meanings for _redact_: to edit text, or to censor/black out content. Can you help us by adding more about your specific problem or how you hope to use the word?

Comment: I've self-censored an image here on SE, because of the concerns in the comments. You can see the usage in my question: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/948/what-does-the-final-in-signify

Comment: That's quite the fair use discussion there! I think _image redacted_ makes perfect sense in that context. To me, _redact_ (in the blacking-out sense) carries a sort of "well-meaning censorship" connotation; it conveys succinctly that there's a good reason the item was cut, like a privacy or law concern.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't specify what to redact, a listener might assume you mean [to sanitize a document or black out text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanitization_%28classified_information%29). There's a strong association with text, but it doesn't mean you can't use the word "redact" with other things.

The current use of *redact* often includes *image redaction*, especially when discussing electronic files such as Word or PDF documents.

The [NSA Redacting with Confidence guide](http://www.nsa.gov/ia/_files/support/I733-028R-2008.pdf) (note, 1.4MB PDF available from [NSA index](http://www.nsa.gov/ia/guidance/security_configuration_guides/current_guides.shtml)) discusses redacting images - for example:

> Select each chart, diagram, image, or segment of text to be redacted and delete that item.

[Adobe PDF tutorials](http://www.adobe.com/designcenter/acrobat/articles/acr8at_redact_print.html) also address this issue with phrases like:

> Redacting text and images in a PDF file

So if you say

> We should redact the diagram on this page.

you'll be understood.

Note: [Redaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redaction) has a specific meaning in literature. I'm assuming you're talking about the *document sanitization* meaning.

Comment: Now that you've told us this, does that mean you have to kill us?

Comment: A common form of image redaction is the blurring or blanking out of vehicle number plates in photos, such as those in Google maps' Street View images. In this case the chief reason is privacy and legal considerations. In this particular example, the redaction relates to the text visible in an image, so it encompasses both categories.

Answer (score 1):

While you might be understood when using it in a different context, it is generally recognized as referring to a process that is only performed on a text.

Answer (score -3):

The definition of [redact:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/redact)

> 1. to compose or draft (an edict, proclamation, etc)
> 2. to put (a literary work, etc) into appropriate form for publication; edit

As you can see, it actually applies to literary works only.